# WebRTC, Browser does not see/hear iOS, Android works

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I have implemented WebRTC in both Android and iOS OSs, they should be able to communicate with a client based on Web, so through a browser such as Chrome.
The problem is that the Browser client cannot see/hear iOS, while iOS can.
With Android everything works correctly.
The most sneaky thing is that if Android or iOS call each other they can see/hear them selves so the problem seems to be the browser.

Is there any particular configuration to add in order to fix the issue?

Here are some parts of Swift code, despite it being quite long.

Part of the WebRTC class

```
private static let factory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory = {
        let videoEncoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory()
        let videoDecoderFactory = RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory()
        return RTCPeerConnectionFactory(encoderFactory: videoEncoderFactory, decoderFactory: videoDecoderFactory)
    }()

public func setupRTC(){
        let config = RTCConfiguration()
        config.iceServers = [RTCIceServer(urlStrings: iceServers)]
        config.sdpSemantics = .unifiedPlan
        config.tcpCandidatePolicy = .disabled;
        config.bundlePolicy = .maxBundle;
        config.rtcpMuxPolicy = .require;
        config.keyType = .ECDSA;
        config.iceInactiveTimeout = 10000
        config.iceUnwritableTimeout = 3000
        config.continualGatheringPolicy = .gatherContinually
        
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints:  nil,
                                              optionalConstraints: nil)
        
        guard let peerConnection = WebRTCClient.factory.peerConnection(with: config, constraints: constraints, delegate: nil) else {
            fatalError("Could not create new RTCPeerConnection")
        }
        

var audioTrackl: RTCAudioTrack?
    var videoTrackl: RTCVideoTrack?
    
    private func createMediaSenders() {
        
        // Audio
        audioTrackl = self.createAudioTrack()
        
        // Video
        videoTrackl = self.createVideoTrack()
        self.localVideoTrack = videoTrackl
        
    }
    
    private func addTracksToPeer(){
        let streamId = "stream"
        self.peerConnection!.add(self.audioTrackl!, streamIds: [streamId])
        self.peerConnection!.add(self.videoTrackl!, streamIds: [streamId])
        self.remoteVideoTrack = self.peerConnection!.transceivers.first { $0.mediaType == .video }?.receiver.track as? RTCVideoTrack
    }
    
    func renderRemoteVideo(to renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {
        self.remoteVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
    }
    
    private func configureAudioSession() {
        self.rtcAudioSession.lockForConfiguration()
        do {
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue)
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat.rawValue)
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint("Error changeing AVAudioSession category: \(error)")
        }
        self.rtcAudioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
    
    private func createAudioTrack() -> RTCAudioTrack {
        let audioConstrains = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: nil)
        let audioSource = WebRTCClient.factory.audioSource(with: audioConstrains)
        let audioTrack = WebRTCClient.factory.audioTrack(with: audioSource, trackId: "audio0")
        
        return audioTrack
    }
    
    private func createVideoTrack() -> RTCVideoTrack {
        let videoSource = WebRTCClient.factory.videoSource()
        
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        self.videoCapturer = RTCFileVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)
        #else
        self.videoCapturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: videoSource)
        #endif
        
        let videoTrack = WebRTCClient.factory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: "video0")
        return videoTrack
    }
    
    func startCaptureLocalVideo(cameraPositon: AVCaptureDevice.Position, renderer: RTCVideoRenderer) {

           let videoWidth =  640
           let videoHeight = 480//640*16/9
           var fps = 30
           
           if let capturer = self.videoCapturer as? RTCCameraVideoCapturer {
               
               var targetDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
               var targetFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
               
               // find target device
               let devicies = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices()
               devicies.forEach { (device) in
                   if device.position ==  cameraPositon {
                       targetDevice = device
                   }
               }

             //   find target format
               let formats = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: targetDevice!)
               formats.forEach { (format) in
                   let fpsR = (format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges.sorted { return $0.maxFrameRate < $1.maxFrameRate }.last)
                   fps = Int(fpsR?.maxFrameRate ?? 30)

                   for _ in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
                       let description = format.formatDescription as CMFormatDescription
                       let dimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(description)

                       if dimensions.width == videoWidth && dimensions.height == videoHeight {
                           targetFormat = format
                       } else if dimensions.width == videoWidth {
                           targetFormat = format
                       }
                   }
               }
               capturer.startCapture(with: targetDevice!, format: targetFormat!, fps: 30)
               self.localVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
               
           }
       }
        
        
        self.peerConnection = peerConnection
        self.addTracksToPeer()
        self.configureAudioSession()
        self.peerConnection!.delegate = self
    }
```

The signalling class simply checks if the received message is an offer/answer/candidate and acts accordingly.

Thanks for any help!